# Unable to log in to webpage using XMLHTTP

Tags: vba, excel, xmlhttprequest

i am trying to login to webpage and download data but unable to get in, its secured site & require pwd. i tried thru post methd but no luck, plz help me where i am going wrong..

`Sub Go_New_XML()
    Dim oHttp As Object. sHTML as String
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oHttp.Open "POST", "http://www.example.com/login.asp", False
    oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    oHttp.send "username=aa@gmail.com&login-password=passss"
    While oHttp.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    sHTML = oHttp.responseText
    Debug.Print sHTML
End Sub`

Comment: Look at the source code of the login page. There are more form elements, which would be sended in normally cases. So redirect=[url encoded URL] and submit=Login. Maybe the site only accepts logins which has all default elements in POST. Also maybe the site tries to prevent automated logins. You should respect that then.

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks for Quick help, can you help me how to add code for redirect & submit=login, i am novice for XHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has to achieve something like this, he has to look into the source of the Login HTML. In this case it shows:

```
        <form name="FrontPage_Form1" action="user_login.asp" method="post" onsubmit="return FrontPage_Form1_Validator(this)" language="JavaScript" id="login-form">
        <fieldset>
            <p><label for="login-username">username</label>

            <input id="login-username" autofocus="" class="round full-width-input" name="username" size="32" value="" type="text">
            </p><br>
            <p><label for="login-password">password</label>

            <input id="login-password" class="round full-width-input" name="password" size="32" value="" type="password">
            </p><br>
            <p>
            <input value="1" name="remember" =""="" type="checkbox">Remember Me</p><br>
            <input name="redirect" value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782351/unable-to-log-in-to-webpage-using-xmlhttp" type="hidden">
            <p>I've <a href="user_forgotpassword.asp">forgotten my password</a>.</p>
            <br><br>
            <input name="submit" value="Login" class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow" type="submit"> 
            or
            <a href="user_signup.asp" class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow">
            REGISTER NOW</a> </fieldset>
        </form>
```

So there are following elements in submit POST:

- username with the username as value
- password with the password as value
- redirect with a URL as value
- submit with "Login" as value

Note, that this are the *names* of the form elements.

The checkbox "remember" is not per default in the submit, because it is a checkbox and gets only submitted, if it is checked.

Maybe the site only accepts logins which has all default elements in POST. If so then try:

```
oHttp.send "username=aa@gmail.com&password=passss&redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&submit=Login"
```

Note that the URL in redirect has to be URL encoded as needed for the type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Also maybe the site tries to prevent automated logins. You should respect that then.

Greetings

Axel